# How to get a cell reference used in a cell for use in a different formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Suppose cells in a column (`TheSheet!A`) contain just references to cells in the column of another sheet, but noncontiguously. For example, give `Sheet!A17` the formula:

```
=OtherSheet!A23
```

Other cells on TheSheet in the same row correspondingly need to reference cells in the referenced row. For example, `TheSheet!B17` would need to reference `OtherSheet!D23`. While the references could be written directly, it would be error-prone. How can these other cells instead use the cell references from column A in their own formulae?

Note the value of the cell isn't a cell address, so `INDIRECT` is insufficient. Similarly, `ROW` by itself is unsuitable as it will return the row of the cell itself, not the cell it references.

Answer (score 1):

The key is [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792), which will return the formula used in a cell.

```
=FORMULATEXT(A17)
```

This value will then need to be parsed into a cell address. As the formula is simply a reference, removing the leading `=` is sufficient. [`RIGHT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087), in its ltr-centric way, can be used to get the trailing portion of a string, though this approach is a little verbose, as it requires the length of the string, requiring `FORMULATEXT` to be used twice. Consequently, we're not going to use it, though it's presented here for reference:

```
=RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(A17), 2, LEN(FORMULATEXT(A17))-1)
```

[`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215) is an option (`SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A17), '=', '')`). A substring function that accepted negative indices would be just about perfect, but Google Sheets doesn't offer one. What it does offer is [`MID`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129), which can be made to work. It also takes a string length; a value longer than the (right portion of the) string can be given and the extra length is essentially ignored.

```
=`MID(FORMULATEXT(A17), 2, 100)`
```

While this is not technically correct, it shouldn't cause an error in this use case, since the formula should never be close to 100 characters long. Another option is [`REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098247) to replace the "=" substring with an empty string: `REPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A17), 1, 1, "")`. We'll use `MID` for brevity & clarity (such as there is in spreadsheet formulae).

We now have a cell address as text. There are a couple ways this can be turned into a cell reference on the same row but in another column. Presented here is [`OFFSET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379), which shifts cell (technically range) references by a given number of rows & columns. For example, to go from column A to column C, use `OFFSET(range, 0, 3)`. Since `OFFSET` takes references, rather than text addresses, the value from the previous formula is passed first through [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377).

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(A17), 2, 100)), 0, 3)
```

This is the desired cell reference.